# Поворачивается изображение на системном активити при увеличении

Tags: android, kotlin, activity

Почему если вызвать из фрагмента

```
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
      addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
      setDataAndType(uri, "image/*")
    })
```

Фото отображается нормально ровно до момента пока не начнешь его трогать, точнее немного увеличивать???
Изображение до того как с ним повзаимодействовать
[image: Изображение до того как с ним повзаимодействовать]

Изображение после того как с ним повзаимодействовать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если точнее - то фотография поворачивается и растягивается в альбомную ориентацию из портретной и так остаётся

- Системный интерфейс при этом не поворачивается, т.е. только сама
  фотография.
- Ориентация в манифесте указана sensorPortrait, но не думаю что это на
  что то влияет, ведь создается активити системное.
- На устройстве запрет на переворот включен.

Comment: Просмотр фото происходит за пределами вашего приложения. Поведение может быть любым в зависимости от вида приложения установленного на устройстве для просмотра.

Comment: @Style-7
получается это системная ошибка? Странно, но при таком же вызове, но из другого URI, все работает нормально